# Sync SQLite database via AirDrop

Tags: ios, sqlite, synchronization

I have an app using SQLite database. Now I want to sync the database via AirDrop between iOS devices. Does anyone have idea how to do that ?

I do not want to send the whole database file since the SQLite database have pictures inside (BLOB). Can I update the differences only ?

Thanks in advance !

Peter

Comment: make a json of record, pass this json on each other device, update each databse from other device passed json.

Comment: Is there any open source library to handle this ?

Comment: i am not sure, search for sqlite database merge, it may help you.

Comment: It seems to download the whole database. Then merge the existing one.

Comment: if chance are less number of record need to merge each time, i would suggest just pass basic details using json on other device, on demand get specific blob data or other details from other device.